# xaml bind value of listbox item to whether is

Tags: wpf, xaml, syncfusion

I am building a WPF application in VS 2012 that uses Code First Entity Framework and the repository and MVVM pattern.

I have two classes: EntityType and LicenseType.

EntityType is specified by the following:

```
    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private string _description;
    private List<LicenseType> _licenseTypes = new List<LicenseType>();
```

LicenseType is declared with:

```
    private int _id;
    private string _name;
    private string _description;
```

And there are Public Properties declared for these private fields.

I am binding an ObservableCollection to a CheckedListBox (Syncfusion product).

No problem.

Underneath it, I am binding another CheckedListBox to an ObservableCollection.

Again, no problem.

What I can't do is set the IsSelected property of the CheckListBoxItem in the LicenseType listbox to true (thereby, "checking" the checkbox) based on whether that particular LicenseType is in the collection of EntityType.LicenseTypes.

Here is the code for my CheckedListBox:

```
         <syncfusion:CheckListBox x:Name="lstAllLicenseTypes" ItemsSource="{Binding   AllLicenseTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" >
           <syncfusion:CheckListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="syncfusion:CheckListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding ????}"/>
                </Style>
            </syncfusion:CheckListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </syncfusion:CheckListBox>
```

I have tried two approaches, the first was to loop through each of the LicenseType listbox items, check whether there was an association with the EntityType's LicenseType collection, and try to set a Property value that was binded to the XAML:

private void ListEntityTypes_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
               var thisEntity = (EntityType) listEntityTypes.SelectedItems[0];

```
        foreach (object t in lstAllLicenseTypes.Items)
        {
            bool hasAssociation = _vmEntityTypes.EntityHasAssociationWithThisLicenseType(thisEntity,(LicenseType) t);
            if (hasAssociation)
            {
                _vmEntityTypes.CurrentEntityIsAssociatedWithCurrentLicenseType = true;
            }
            else
            {
                _vmEntityTypes.CurrentEntityIsAssociatedWithCurrentLicenseType = false;
            }
        }

    }
```

The purpose here is to bind to the property "CurrentEntityIsAssociatedWithCurrentLicenseType". This did not work. I think it did not work because for each item in the CheckedListBox, the property value was updated, and therefore, at the end, it was false, so no item was checked.

The other approach was similar to above but I was trying to manually "check" the listbox item, however I could never cast the LicenseType back to a CheckListItem.

In general, what I'm weak on is working with collections of records that relate to other collections of data and building an interface that allows users to clearly add and relate different tables.

Any help would be great,

Thanks!
Paul

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a converter. Bind the IsChecked to a property that wraps the list (EntityType.LicenseTypes), and then use an IValueConverter that returns a Boolean. Pass the LicenseType for the CheckedListBoxItem as a ConverterParameter.

Implement IPropertyNofity on the EntityType class.

When the EntityType.LicenseTypes list changes, Use the PropertyNotify on the wrapped property, and isChecked will update.

Psuedo code:

```
public class EntityType : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public List<LicenseType> LicenseTypes
    { 
        get { return _licenseTypes; }
        set
        {
            _licenseTypes = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("LicenseTypes");
        }
    }

}

public class ListToCheckedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter ...
    {
        var list = (List<LicenseType>)value;
        var type = (LicenseType)parameter;
        return list.Contains(type);
    }
    ...
}
```

XAML:

```
    <syncfusion:CheckListBox x:Name="lstAllLicenseTypes" ItemsSource="{Binding   AllLicenseTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" >
       <syncfusion:CheckListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="syncfusion:CheckListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" 
                    Value="{Binding Path=LicenseTypes, 
                            Converter = ListToCheckedConverter,
                            ConverterParameter = Header}"/>
            </Style>
        </syncfusion:CheckListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </syncfusion:CheckListBox>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can bind the IsSelected to the CheckedListBoxItem's Header itself, and pass a EntityList in, but then you lose the ability to auto-update if the EntityList updates.

Comment: Alternatively, alternatively, you can use a multibind and bind both the Header and the EntityList, and if either updates. Just a few ideas.

Comment: I implemented the changes you gave in the first solution, however, the Converter function is NOT firing. Here's the code:

Comment: public class ListToCheckedConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var list = (ObservableCollection<LicenseType>)value;
            var type = (LicenseType)parameter;
            return list.Contains(type);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

Comment: The IValueConverter function Convert is NOT firing.

Comment: Then most likely the binding path isn't being resolved correctly. I'll take a look at this when I get more time.